# nslookup and ping succeed reaching a server on the local network, but not from the browser Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: networking, server, dns

We have a local network, there is a DHCP and two DNS servers on the network (Windows server 2016). We have also newly installed Jenkins and Gitlab on two different CentOS 7 machines.I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 My problem is that I can access the Windows servers' shared files, I can ssh to the CentOS machines, ping works as well as nslookup, but when I go from my browser to gitlab.domain.local, I get server not found. I tried from Windows and a Mac machines, all work fine. Only the Ubuntu machine doesn't.

My `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like this

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 10.1.0.18
nameserver 10.1.0.19
```

these are the correct DNS servers on our local network. I have seen many close problems and tried their solutions and nothing worked so far.

`dig gitlab`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> gitlab
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 15721
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
; COOKIE: 91b4c9cfb8b38b47 (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gitlab.                IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.1.0.18#53(10.1.0.18)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 06 12:51:14 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

and this is `dig` with FQDN

```
dig gitlab.domain.local


; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> gitlab.domain.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52916
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
; COOKIE: 97d486994c884538 (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gitlab.domain.local.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gitlab.domain.local.    3600    IN  A   10.1.0.13

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.1.0.18#53(10.1.0.18)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 06 12:53:39 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 78
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version? What about `http://gitlab/`?  Please edit/add the output of `dig gitlab.domain.local` and maybe of `dig gitlab` too.

Comment: is there any proxy server settings in the browser ?

Comment: There is a proxy configured for outgoing traffic only (to the internet). I tried with the proxy on and off.. I keep getting the same result!

Comment: What is the result when the browser points to `http://10.1.0.13`
`

Comment: it loads gitlab successfully... only with the IP address

Comment: you may have to look at the httpd server, the `ServerName` option i guess